# Microsoft "New Executable" format?

Tags: windows, exe, executable

I am trying to develop a utility to diagnose Microsoft **NE-formatted EXEs**.  One thing I'm not clear on is whether 64-bit NEs **exist** at all. I know that PE-formatted EXEs can be either 32 or 64 bit but not sure about NE. Any one know?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Executable : "The New Executable (abbreviated NE or NewEXE) is a 16-bit .exe file format" ... "While designed for 16-bit OSes, NE executables can be run on 32-bit Windows." ... "64-bit Windows cannot run 16-bit programs on the processor without the help of an emulator."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NE, LE and LX exe formats are older and 16-bit or 32-bit. NE is from DOS. LE is for DOS extenders, Windows 3, OS/2 and [VxD](https://msfn.org/board/topic/149053-vxd-versions-in-xp-and-in-dos/) drivers on Windows 95/98. [LX](https://web.archive.org/web/20170919101239/http://www.textfiles.com/programming/FORMATS/lxexe.txt) is for DOS extenders and OS/2. The VxDs and extenders can be 16/32-bit hybrids.

It would make no sense to try to put 64-bit code in one, they are not even optimal for 32-bit code which is why PE was invented.

The format has been dead for a long time. Look for old SDKs and books from before 1995 if you want detailed information.